# Do compounds exist in Spanish which are not nouns or are nouns other than than of the form (3ps verb + pl noun)?

Tags: morfología, compuestos, vocabulario

In Romance languages, compound words are much rarer than in Germanic language such as English, but they do exist.

My favourite kind of word formation in Spanish is the one that results in words such as *abrebotellas* and *espantapájaros* which are made by compounding a verb in the third person present singular indicative with a plural noun.

But are there other kinds of compound words in Spanish? I'm sure there are but after wracking my brain all I could come up with was *quemarropa* which is about as close as you can get to the kind I just described.

**Do other kinds of compound exist in Spanish?**

(I'm not looking for a complete list, just a yes no answer with either a couple of examples or link or reference with further reading.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Yes.

I'm listing a few examples from [this link (Palabras compuestas)](http://www.maritacazapalabras.com.ar/palabras_compuestas.htm):

- **Noun + noun = noun**: [mapamundi](http://buscon.rae.es/draeI/SrvltGUIBusUsual?LEMA=mapamundi)
- **Noun + adjective = noun & adjective**: [pelirrojo](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pelirrojo)
- **Adjective + noun = noun**: [mediodía](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/mediod%C3%ADa)
- **Verb + verb = noun**: [tejemaneje](http://buscon.rae.es/draeI/SrvltGUIBusUsual?LEMA=tejemaneje)
- **Verb + pronoun + verb = noun**: [hazmerreír](http://buscon.rae.es/draeI/SrvltConsulta?TIPO_BUS=3&LEMA=hazmerre%C3%ADr) (more triple combinations [here](http://lengua.laguia2000.com/gramatica/composicion-de-palabras))

The Wikipedia article [Composición (lingüística)](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composici%C3%B3n_%28ling%C3%BC%C3%ADstica%29) also has more examples.

Comment: I have a feeling there are even some prepositions or adverbs which are compounds but, again I can't think of any so I might be wrong.

Comment: Like 'sinvergüenza', 'contrasentido'?

Comment: *tentempié*: verb + pronoun + preposition + noun.

Answer (score 10):

I have always loved this one, since I first read it in [Mafalda](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mafalda) as a child: **[correveidile](http://buscon.rae.es/draeI/SrvltConsulta?TIPO_BUS=3&LEMA=correveidile)**.
It's a whole sentence in one word.

Comment: +1 Nice one, I love it!

Comment: +1 Indeed, nice word!

Answer (score 3):

Some used in Colombia:

- Cogeculos: Some situations become a *cogeculos* when they get out of control. For example: `Se armó un cogeculos tremendo`.
- [Chiflamicas](http://www.tubabel.com/definicion/26850-llavear): A really bad musician. I believe it's the composition of *chiflar/silbar* (whistle) and micas (*mico*, perhaps?) Couldn't find anything on Google that would explain how the word came into existence but definitely looks like a composition of 2 words.

Some others:

- [Otrosí](http://buscon.rae.es/draeI/SrvltConsulta?TIPO_BUS=3&LEMA=otros%C3%AD)
- [Dondequiera](http://buscon.rae.es/draeI/SrvltConsulta?TIPO_BUS=3&LEMA=dondequiera)
- [Decimoprimero](http://www.eltiempo.com/vida-de-hoy/educacion/consejos-para-mejorar-su-ortografia_10927579-4)

Comment: In Perú, `Cogeculos` would definitely lower your reputation with the ladies :)